# python daemon stdout,stderr redirect; how to?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, stdout, daemon, stderr

I have this small snippet of my larger py file, wherein I'm trying to redirect the stdout,stderr to two separate files on my desktop.

FYI: I could successfully run the same lines without daemon. (#thread.daemon  = True)
Let me know if I have to provide further details.

[PS: I'm actually trying to run seleniumRC script in the same function]

```
def onCallDelete():
    tenantId="Codebreakers"
    import time,os, sys
    time.sleep(2)
    os.chdir('/Users/pie/Desktop')
    sys.stdout = open('stdoutf.txt', 'w') #assigning file descriptor
    sys.stderr = open('stderrf.txt', 'w') #assigning file descriptor
    sys.stdout.write("hellooooe, this logs to a file")

    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stderr.close()

thread = threading.Thread(target=onCallDelete)
thread.daemon  = True
thread.start()
```